GetIWorkspace2 failed with "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation"
I am trying to use VeriStand C# API to interact with VeriStand.
Based on the official tutorial, I wrote my code:
using NationalInstruments.VeriStand.ClientAPI;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string gatewayIp = "localhost";

        try
        {
            // Initialize Factory class instance to access NI VeriStand system
            Factory factory = new Factory();
            Console.WriteLine("Factory created successfully");
        
            IWorkspace2 workspace = factory.GetIWorkspace2(gatewayIp);
            Console.WriteLine("Workspace obtained successfully");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error type: {ex.GetType()}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Error message: {ex.Message}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Error stack trace: {ex.StackTrace}");
        }
    }
}

Based on the log, you can see Factory created successfully, but then GetIWorkspace2 failed immediately:
Factory created successfully

Error type: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Error message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Error stack trace:    at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceOfT()
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance[T]()
   at NationalInstruments.VeriStand.ClientAPI.ClientServerManager`1.GetClientServer(String address)
   at NationalInstruments.VeriStand.ClientAPI.ClientServerManagerInstances.GetDataServices(String address)
   at NationalInstruments.VeriStand.ClientAPI.WorkspaceImpl..ctor(String address)
   at NationalInstruments.VeriStand.ClientAPI.WorkspaceAggregator.Create(String address)
   at NationalInstruments.VeriStand.ClientAPI.Factory.GetIWorkspace2(String gateway_ip_address)
   at Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Hongb\Documents\Git\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 18

I can confirm if I use VeriStand UI to deploy "Engine Demo" to the gateway at localhost, it works well.

Any guide would be appreciate, thanks!

You should print out ex.InnerException too.

Thanks @shingo guide in the comment! After printing full error by Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); with inner exception, it points me the correct direction.
The error shows it is missing System.ServiceModel.NetNamedPipeBinding. I realize this has to be a .NET Framework 4 app instead of .NET Core 8 app, here is full working code that deploys "Engine Demo" to the gateway at localhost
using NationalInstruments.VeriStand.ClientAPI;

namespace VeriStandController
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string gatewayIp = "localhost";
            string systemDefinitionPath = @"C:\Users\Public\Documents\National Instruments\NI VeriStand 2024\Examples\Stimulus Profile\Engine Demo\Engine Demo.nivssdf";

            Factory factory = new Factory();
            IWorkspace2 workspace = factory.GetIWorkspace2(gatewayIp);

            // Connect to the system and deploy the system definition file
            workspace.ConnectToSystem(systemDefinitionPath, true, 60000); // ms
            
        }
    }
}

This code now can succeed deploying the "Engine Demo" in the VeriStand.
